# UWP Combobox doesn't return a selected value in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I struggle getting a combobox to work in a MVVM UWP app.
I have it working in the code behind. That was not too difficult but now I have a ViewModel  that gives problems. As usual I spend a day or so on the internet to find a similar question and solution but nothing there. Whatever I try results in a Null Exception and I can't figure out why I cannot simply select a value from the Combobox and transfer it to my code.

This is how I did it in the code behind and where "(int)golfdropdown.SelectedValue" did the job.

```
   private void WireUpSpelerDropDown()
    {
        string sql = "select * from Golfclub ";
        var golfclublijst = SqliteDataAccess.LoadData<GolfclubModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());

        golfclublijst.ForEach(x => golfclub.Add(x));

        golfclubDropDown.ItemsSource = golfclub;
        golfclubDropDown.DisplayMemberPath = "Naam";
        golfclubDropDown.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
    }

enter code here
```

This is a piece of my mvvm code:

```
public class SpelerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<SpelerModel> Spelers = new ObservableCollection<SpelerModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<GolfclubModel> Golfclubs = new ObservableCollection<GolfclubModel>();
    
    public bool NewRecordClearFields = false;

    public int GolfclubId { get; set; } = 3;

    public SpelerModel NewSpeler { get; set; }
    public SpelerViewModel()
    {
        NewSpeler = new SpelerModel();
        GetData();
        WireUpSpelerDropDown();
    }
    private void WireUpSpelerDropDown()
    {
       
        string sql = "select * from Golfclub ";
        var golfclublijst = SqliteDataAccess.LoadData<GolfclubModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());

        golfclublijst.ForEach(x => Golfclubs.Add(x));
    }
```

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="golfclubDropDown" 
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Viewmodel.Golfclubs, Mode=OneWay}"                          
                      SelectedValue ="{x:Bind Viewmodel.GolfclubId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Naam"
                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                      Header="Homeclub"
                      Margin=" 8"
                      MinWidth="200">
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you check the `SelectedValue` on your side? When using your code to test on my side, I could see the `GolfclubId` changed correctly in the `Combobox.SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: I checked it with a Integer variable: public int SelectedId{ get; set;} I also implemented your suggestion to make an SelectionChanged event to display a messagebox. public void Geselecteerd()
        {
            MessageDialog messagedialog = new MessageDialog($"output = {SelectedId}");
            _ = messagedialog.ShowAsync();
        }

Comment: I'm testing your code in a blank UWP project with some test data. Could you please reproduce this issue in a blank UWP project with the code you posted and share the sample here?